# Capture keyboard interrupt in bash

Tags: linux, bash, centos, interrupt, sigint

I have a function in bash which captures the keyboard interrupt. The function looks like this:

```
user_interrupt(){
        echo -e "\n\nKeyboard Interrupt detected."
        sleep 2
        echo -e "\n Cleaning up..."
        rm -rf /usr/local/src/mysources
}
```

Now, in the same script, I have another function called `install()` that installs a few packages from source one after the other using the standard `./configure`, `make`, `make install` process. The idea is to capture the user interrupt from while running the 3 installations one after the other. Question is, where do I place the following statements:

```
trap user_interrupt SIGINT
trap user_interrupt SIGTSTP
```

So should I place it as the first statement inside the `install()` function? Or do I need an `if-else` condition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess that you want to `exit` after detecting user interrupt (of course after the clean up act in done).  If that is so, you need to say `exit` after the `rm -rf ...` line in your function.  Unless you do so, `trap` would catch a signal `SIGINT` for example, perform the tasks in your `user_interrupt` function and the script would continue to execute.

To answer the other question, simply define the function you've mentioned at the top of your script followed by the two `trap` commands and subsequently by your remaining code (the `install()` function and so on).  `trap` would catch the mentioned signals and you do not need any explicit handling for that.

Comment: did u mean at the beginning of the `install()` function?

Comment: No, outside the function; before it.  I assume that you'd want to capture interrupts for all functions in the script.